# I set AutoComplete to off - my page isn’t kept properly. can’t go forward/backwards or refresh without the filtered results in the page disappearing

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

With Autocomplete set to Off When I click the 'back' button or the 'refresh/reload' button in the browser my search/filtered results disappear. How can I have the results page stay with the keyword whilst navigating back and fourth to the page, or refreshing/reloading. Do I need to have my search word and page assigned to a href address bar Eg: mysite.com/?search=words and historySession involved in the concept? - My JavaScript knowledge I admit is limited, but I do know that this problem can surely be solved

JS

```
<body>
<script>
var input, table, rows, noMatches, tr, markInstance;

$(document).ready(function init() {
input = document.getElementById('myInput');
noMatches = document.getElementById('noMatches');

table = document.querySelectorAll('#myTable table tr:first-child');
rows = document.querySelectorAll('#myTable table tr');

markInstance = new Mark(table);
if(document.getElementById('myInput').value.length >0){
ContactsearchFX();
}
input.addEventListener('keyup', _.debounce(ContactsearchFX, 250));
});


function ContactsearchFX() {
  resetContent();
  markInstance.unmark({ done: highlightMatches });
}



function resetContent() {
    $('.noMatchErrorText').remove(); 
    //Remove this line to have a log of searches

    //noMatches.textContent = '';
  rows.forEach(function(row) {
    $(row).removeClass('show'); 
  });
}

function highlightMatches() {
  markInstance.mark(input.value, {
    each: showRow,
    noMatch: onNoMatches,
    exclude: ['.nonsearch']
  })
}



function showRow(element) {
//alert(element);
  $(element).parents('tr').addClass('show');              $(element).parents('tr').siblings('tr').addClass('show');
        //Parents incase of several nestings
}



function onNoMatches(text) {
  $('#myInput').after('<p class="noMatchErrorText">No records match: "' +     text +                      '"</p>'); 
}



/* Prevents Return/Enter key from doing anything */

$(document).on('submit', 'form', function(e){
/* on form submit find the trigger */
if( $(e.delegateTarget.activeElement).not('input, textarea').length == 0 ){
    /* if the trigger is not between selectors list, return super false */
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
} 
});
```

CSS

```
</script>

<style>
.input-wrap  {
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

#myInput:invalid ~ .hints {
  display: block;
}



#noMatches:empty, #noMatches:empty + .hints {
  display: none;
}


.style1 tr {
  display: none;
}


.style1 .show {
  display: table-row;
}



#myTable table tr:first-child td mark {
background: orange;
font-weight: bold;
color: black;
}
mark {
background: initial;
}    .style1  {
text-align: left;
}
</style>
```

HTML

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.11/lodash.min.js">
</script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mark.js/8.11.1
/mark.min.js"></script>
<head>
<body>
<div class="input-wrap">
<label>
Search 
<input id="myInput" type="text" spellcheck="false"
   placeholder="Search Titles"/>
<div class="hintsWrap">
<p id="noMatches"></p>
<p class="hints">
Hints: type "Title1", "Title2", "Title3"...
</p>
</div>
</label>
</div>
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<table id="myTable" style="width: 100%" class="style1">
    <tr>
        <td>
<br />
<br />
<table style="width: 100%">
    <tr>
        <td>
        <table style="width: 100%">
            <tr>
                <th class="style1">Type</th>
                <td>type1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th class="style1">Title</th>
                <td>title1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th class="style1">Description</th>
                <td>description1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th class="style1">Date</th>
                <td>date1</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
 </table>

 <br />

        <table style="width: 100%">
            <tr>
                <th class="style1">Type</th>
                <td>type2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th class="style1">Title</th>
                <td>title2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th class="style1">Description</th>
                <td>description2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th class="style1">Date</th>
                <td>date2</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    <br />
    <br />
        <table style="width: 100%">
            <tr>
                <th class="style1">Type</th>
                <td>type3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th class="style1">Title</th>
                <td>title3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th class="style1">Description</th>
                <td>description3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th class="style1">Date</th>
                <td>date3</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
      <br />
```

Comment: Why not store your search results in browser storage and retrieve them upon reload? `localStorage.setItem("item", "data")`, `localStorage.getItem("item","data")`. These will set/get only one item at a time. If you need more advanced storage, look into IndexedDB and its various wrapper libraries like Dexie, etc. But your idea about updating the URL upon search then parsing that URL upon reload could also work.

Comment: @Dshiz yes that could maybe be a solution. Now I'm trying how to figure how to disable the browsers autocomplete using 'display none' but not sure about the code. Wonder if you or anyone knows the answer to that one

Comment: Technically this should be a new question. But here you go: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion